# how convert this part of .NET code to PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net

How can i write this code of `.NET` to `PHP`

```
string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string encryptedContent = Cryptography.EncryptRijndael(content, guid);
Request Request = new Request
{
    Password = encryptedContent,
    requestNumber = 0,
    UserName = "",
    MAC = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Cryptography.EncryptRSA("Token=" + guid + ";" +
              "Hash=" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Cryptography.GetSHA256Hash(content))),
                   ClientPublicKey, 4096)),
    version = "",
    customerCode = 3312
};
```

this is preparing parameters of an API to call and get the response
but I can't write this in `PHP` language

Comment: in php, you doesn't need to declare string. you just need to put "$" at first of variable. e.g: $guid.. Please check on php.net for more detail

Comment: this is .NET code ...

Comment: i know.. i just inform you how to convert it to PHP..

Comment: problem is not a "$". i know php syntax. problem is rijenda, problem is cryptography class, problem is getByte method and ....

Comment: Glad you know the real problem.. You need to find other party library to support what you need from that code.. After that, if any error happen, you can ask here. Instead of directly ask to feedspoon you